# Node.js: Cannot find module 'express'

Tags: node.js

I ran the following from the npm/node_modules dir (OSX):

```
npm install express
```

and I see the express dir in the node_modules dir.

I then try and launch my connectionCounter.js file, but get the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'express'
```

I've tried executing "node connectionCounter.js" from several places (npm dir, express dir, dir connectionCounter.js is in), to see if that will work -- but no luck.

Does anyone know where I should be running the node command from?

Thanks.

Comment: post your app file with dependencies please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use

```
npm install express
```

in the root folder of your project. If you want to install it globally, use

```
npm install -g express
```

Answer (score 0):

> "I ran the following from the npm/node_modules dir "

I think this is your problem. Run that command in the directory connectionCounter.js is in. Your directory structure should look like this after you run that command:

```
dir/
|-connectionCounter.js
|-node_modules/
  |-express/
    |-all the stuff in express
```